how do i position text over an image using css?
I've been trying to place text on top of an image for my webpage and so far here is my code:
html:
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="background" src="header.png" alt="Background Image">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="SignIn">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Sign In</h1>
        <p>Enter your credentials below</p>
      </div>
  </div>

css:
h1.entry-title {
  font: weight 600;
  text-align: center;
}

.SignIn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

Im trying to do this
 the sign in part

Why not just use background-image?

i tried but i had trouble getting the right dimensions, i got it now but thank still

Place background as actual background image for #content and add position: relative, so that absolute element would be relative to #content.


h1.entry-title {
  font: weight 600;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/500/300?grayscale&blur=2') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.SignIn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="SignIn">
      <h1 class="entry-title">Sign In</h1>
      <p>Enter your credentials below</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




i just tried it and it worked! thank you
